# "Surprise or surprising" What word choice would be correct here?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

I came across this question and I should decide which of these two answers is correct.

> The spectators showed _____ at the unexpected victory of the local
>   basketball team.
>
> a) surprising
>
> b) surprise

I am told that the correct answer is "b".

> The spectators showed **surprise** at the unexpected victory of the local
>   basketball team.

But I don't think that's right, because if '**surprise**' is an answer, it would be '**a surprise**', or '**their surprise**'. Of course, "**surprise**" could be also used as an uncountable noun.

Which answer is correct and why?

Comment: We don't usually use articles with general phenomena or subjects, like *surprise*.  For example: the student studied *philosophy*, not "a philosophy"; the speaker advocated *democracy*, not "a democracy"; *curiosity* can be dangerous, not "a curiosity".

Comment: thank you. i knew you don't use it with articles.

Answer (score 3):

Surprising is an adjective that cannot be used in the sentence.

You show or express surprise.  The surprise is both a countable and uncountable noun. In the context of the sentence, it's an uncountable noun meaning a feeling caused by an unusual or unexpected happening.

So the right answer is:

The spectators showed surprise..........